# System Memory Not getting Freed up in Ec2 instance even after java process /docker container is stopped

Tags: spring-boot, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

We have tomcat in docker inside an ec2 instance. A java application which uses SQS, Spring boot runs in tomcat. As the load increases we see that the system memory increases slowly and have to restart the ec2-instance to clear the memory.

During all this time, The heap remains stable. 
we were able to slowdown the memory growth with a chnage to make JAXB context singleton.

Not sure what is using the System memory and how to clear it or prevent it. Does spring boot and it litener threads taking this memory ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *The heap remains stable* so either it is stable or it is growing.

Comment: Heap memory is not growing, but the System memory goes up slowly.

Comment: Ask AWS support about it then.

Comment: Thank you for you response .When we do a top command , it shows that java process is usng the memory. but in the monitoring  tool heap is 2g (max 4g).  So aws says Java uses the memory. i am trying to find out what can use native memory (off heap)  from my java application

Comment: Show me the chart from JVisualm